# Validation Error when filtering by UUID Django

Tags: python, django, validation, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am attempting to return all the friends of friends of a certain user who is the author of the relationship.

However, I keep getting this error:

ValidationError at /author/posts
["“[UUID('8c02a503-7784-42f0-a367-1876bbfad6ff')]” is not a valid UUID."]

```
class Author(AbstractUser):
    ...
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    ...

class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

class Friend(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('author','friend'),)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='author')
    friend = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='friend')
```

This foaf line in particular is where the error is coming from. How else could I do this?

```
friends = Friend.objects.filter(author=userUUID)
foafs = Friend.objects.filter(friend=[friend.friend.uuid for friend in friends])
```

Comment: What is `userUUID`?

Comment: Also include the full stacktrace and the code that the error originates from.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing two things to fix here:

1. The lookup should be `friend__in` 'cause you are passing a list o UUIDs.
2. You need to convert the `UUID` object to a string using `friend.friend.uuid)`

The solution proposed is the follwing:

```
foafs = Friend.objects.filter(friend__in=[str(friend.friend.uuid) for friend in friends])
```